# ASP.NET Webapplication unavailable on Live Environment - How to troubleshoot

Tags: debugging, iis, iis-6, asp.net-3.5

I have a asp.net 3.5 web application which is deployed on server 2003 and IIS 6. After running fine for a few weeks it goes "Down" and by down I mean that when I try and access it the browser looks like it's loading but never actually serves the page. After an IIS reset it loads quickly again.

My question is what are the steps and tools I should use in tracking the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

First point of interest would be the event viewer, second the iis logs. If you still do not find the error then performance counters could help you out there.

Comment: What performance counters should I be looking at, queued threads? IIS just doesn't seem to serve the site, however another site on the same iis is being served.

Comment: ASP.NET Apps v2.0.50727

Requests Failed / Not Found / Rejected

Infrastructure Errors

Errors During Compilation / Execution / Precompilation